# Unable to access filename in multer

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, server, multer

After looking through numerous documentation on `Multer` I believe that I have the proper setup on my express server. However, each time I attempt to access the `req.files.filename` attribute of my incoming file, the value is returned as undefined.

Here is my Express server side code:

```js
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: '../Uploads',
            filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname)
        });
        
        const upload = multer({
          storage: storage
        });
    
    Router.post("/", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
      debug.log("connected");
      debug.log(req.file);
      debug.log(req.body);
    
      if (!req.files) {
        debug.log("receiving connection but file not found");
        res.send({
          status: false,
          message: "No file uploaded",
        });
      } else {
        debug.log("receiving connection and file found");
    
        try {
          debug.log(req.files.filename);
          debug.log("attempting to save file" + req.files);
          const post = await new Post({
            title: req.files.filename,
            owner: req.body.owner,
            industry: req.body.industry,
          });
```

If I understand correctly, calling `upload.single` should make `req.file.filename` a usable attribute, but it does not seem to be working.

**EDIT:**

I solved this problem FINALLY!

Apparently using the `app.use(fileUpload());` middleware was somehow interfering with `Multer`.

Before when I had `app.use(fileUpload());` enabled I could access the file through `req.files`, but the file wouldn't save.

After commenting out `app.use(fileUpload());` I can access the file through `req.file` and it will save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a single file (`upload.single`), look at `req.file`, not `req.files`.

Comment: I agree that your logic makes sense. However, when I tried logging req.file instead of req.files I get undefined. I believe the problem is moreso that for some reason my file is not saving correctly in the "storage" function which is why filename is never called.